# Mysql Query for image search

Tags: mysql

I am making a website in php mysql for images gallery website where there would be thousands of images.
My table structures are in the image on this link
[here](http://indiasfreedomstruggle.website.org/imgs/question.jpg)

now what i want is when the user searches for the word "pink" it should display both images from the image table. However if the user searches "pink flower" it should display only the first image. this is just an example. the user may even search for "beautiful pink flower"...
I just need the mysql query for the same. I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks in advance for any kind of help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, after running `explode( ' ', $serachTags )` or something to obtain each tag.

```
SELECT
   images.img_name,
   images.img_url
FROM
   images,
   connections,
   tags AS tagA,
   tags AS tagB,
   tags AS tagC,
   ...
WHERE
   images.img_id = connections.img_id AND
   tagA.tag_id = connections.tag_id AND
   tagA.tag_name = 'name1' AND
   tagB.tag_id = connections.tag_id AND
   tagB.tag_name = 'name2' AND
   tagC.tag_id = connections.tag_id AND
   tagC.tag_name = 'name3' AND
   ...
```

I. e. for flower and pink you could do:

```
SELECT
   images.img_name,
   images.img_url
FROM
   images,
   connections,
   tags AS tagA,
   tags AS tagB
WHERE
   images.img_id = connections.img_id AND
   tagA.tag_id = connections.tag_id AND
   tagA.tag_name = 'flower' AND
   tagB.tag_id = connections.tag_id AND
   tagB.tag_name = 'pink'
```

Comment: hey andreas, sorry for replying late... first of all thanks for the query but it seems like i am making some mistake in the query you gave me...can you please give me an exact query for exactly the two words 'flower' and 'pink' so that i can copy paste it in my localhost to check if its working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Alas your query din't work. It returns me zero rows of result :(

Comment: I did not have time to test it, but try adding one of the WHERE clauses at a time and figure out where it is filtering out too much =)